# Almost everywhere smooth vector field and its flow.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Smooth vector fields give rise to smooth flows. Do Lipschitz and almost everywhere (with respect to volume) smooth vector fields give rise to almost everywhere smooth flows? To clarify is the flow map, $\phi_t(\cdot):M\to M$, almost surely smooth with respect to volume for all positive $t$.

I suspect not since if the flow pushes a particle across a section where the vector field is not smooth the flow would no longer be smooth.

Are there any simple counter examples?

Comment: Not sure from context how you're measuring "almost everywhere" but a natural first example to consider is the one-dimensional vector field $X = \partial_x$ if $x < 0$ and $X = 0$ if $0 \leq x$ on the real line, whose flow lines starting from $x_0 < 0$ hit the origin in finite time.

Comment: "almost everywhere" with respect to Lebesgue measure.  The example will give rise to almost surely smooth flows. They will be smooth on the intervals \(-\infty, -a\), \(-a, 0\) and \(0, \infty \) for some positive $a$.

Comment: My uncertainty (which was not clear from my prior comment) was whether "almost everywhere" refers to (e.g.) smoothness of the flow map on $M\times\mathbf{R}$, to sets of initial conditions in $M$ with smooth flow for all time/all positive time/some open interval, or something else. <> Is the question something like: If $M$ is a smooth manifold equipped with a volume density, $X$ is a measurable vector field on $M$ that is smooth a.e., and $M_0$ denotes the set of points in $M$ for which the flow exists for some open interval about $0$, can the complement of $M_0$ have positive measure?

Comment: All positive time. So if the vector field is Lipchitz and almost everywhere smooth, is the flow map $\phi_t(\cdot):M\to M$ almost everywhere smooth with respect to the volume density for every positive $t$.